# Drop Down Menu inside Md-tab

Tags: angular-material

Is it possible to put drop down menu inside one of the tabs in MD-TABS. Something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Was able to do this with following.

```
<md-tab >
            <md-menu>
                <div ng-click="$mdOpenMenu($event)">
                    <span>Testing</span>
                    <md-icon md-font-icon="fa fa-caret-down"></md-icon>
                </div>
                <md-menu-content>
                    <md-menu-item>
                        <md-button>
                            <md-icon md-menu-align-target></md-icon>
                            Redial
                        </md-button>
                    </md-menu-item>
                    <md-menu-item>
                        <md-button>
                            <md-icon md-menu-align-target></md-icon>
                            Redial
                        </md-button>
                    </md-menu-item>
                    <md-menu-item>
                        <md-button>
                            <md-icon md-menu-align-target></md-icon>
                            Redial
                        </md-button>
                    </md-menu-item>
                    <md-menu-item>
                        <md-button>
                            <md-icon md-menu-align-target></md-icon>
                            Redial
                        </md-button>
                    </md-menu-item>
                </md-menu-content>
            </md-menu>
        </md-tab>
```